# Is LoRaWan only accessible with an internet connection?

Tags: lora, lorawan

I'm planning to build an IoT project for an oil palm plantation through the use of an Arduino and an Android Mobile application for my final year project in University. As plantations have low to no communication signals which includes wifi, it is possible to implement LoRaWAN without access to the internet/use/ of a web-based application?

Answer (score 3):

The LoRaWAN *node* does not need any other communications channel aside from LoRaWAN, of course. Would not make any sense otherwise. ;-)

The *gateway* however does need a connection to the server application that is to be used as a central instance for your use case. Usually this is an existing LoRaWAN cloud service such as The Things Network (TTN) with your application connected behind, but in theory you could connect the gateway to your very own central, making your whole network independent. This is possible because LoRa uses frequency bands free for use (ISM bands) so anyone can become a „network operator“. The TTN software is available as Open Source, for example.

Connection from the gateway to the central is usually done via existing Ethernet/WiFi infrastructures or mobile internet (3G/4G), whatever suits best.

Besides, the LoRa modules available for Arduinos can be used for a low-level, point-to-point LoRa (not LoRaWAN) connection between two such modules. No gateway here. Maybe that is an option, too, for your use case.

Comment: There are also possibilities for an all-in-one, standalone implementation of gateway and LoRaWAN server infrastructure on one host. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72713880/create-a-lorawan-gateway-server/72727685#72727685

Answer (score 2):

The LoraWAN is using the Gateway connected to some kind of cloud, for example the TTN network which is community based. If you live in a bigger city you have good chances to have a TTN Gateway in your area.

You can however connect two Lora nodes together to get a point to point connection. You can send data from Node1, which is connected to some kind of sensor and batterypowered, to Node2, which is stationary and stores all the data to a flashdrive for example. From this flashdrive you can import the data to a website or you could use an application like Node-Red to display the data on a Dashboard.

[Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Dragino-LoRa-GPS-Tracker-1/) you will find instructions on how to send Data from one Lora-Node to another.

[Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Lora-Temperature-Dashboard/) you will find instuctions on how to use Node-Red to display your Lora-Data. You will have to change the input from the TTN-Cloud to a textfile on your Raspberry, or whatever gateway you use. (Optional)

Comment: Could you sum up what those links are providing in case they just dissapear?