# Create a LoRaWAN gateway server

Tags: lora, lorawan

I'm looking for a solution to create my own LoRaWAN gateway that can also be the server.

I would like to get data from any classic LoRaWAN sensor to my own gateway, decrypt and store them locally without internet or the TTN network.

Does anyone know whether it's possible and a way to begin?

Thank you.

Soulsedge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the LoRaWAN protocol is quite extensive, it seems not reasonable to implement the gateway as well as the server on your own. Instead you could take open source implementations of all necessary components and integrate them on one host.

For the gateway you will need a low-level interface (SPI) to the LoRaWAN gateway/concentrator chip (Semtech SX130x) of your hardware. This is possible on a Raspberry Pi, for example. Depends on you specific gateway module, of course.

For the other infrastructure you could resort to either [The Things Stack](https://www.thethingsindustries.com/docs/getting-started/installation/) or [Chirpstack](https://www.chirpstack.io), both of which can be installed on a decent Linux box (including RasPi). Docker images are available IIRC. Communication between GW software and LoRaWAN server is via IP, so no problem doing this locally. You can even add the backend software on the same host, i.e. Node-RED, InfluxDB, Grafana etc., as far as hardware resources (CPU, RAM) will suffice.

PS: I just discovered that – of course – exactly all this has already been done: [Balena Standalone LoRaWAN GW](https://hub.balena.io/organizations/xoseperez/projects/standalone-lorawan-gw).